# (python.game.battleship) how to code and print ships as a symbol, for example "@" on my side of board

Tags: python

Could anyone here please help me?
If printing a board code is as following:

```
board = []
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
for row in board:
    print(" ".join(row))
```

then how to code and print ships as a symbol,
for example "@" on my side of board?

Big thanks in advance

I tried a few, but none worked.

Comment: You say you have "*tried a few*". Can you [edit] your question and show what you've tried?

Comment: for what i tried i got syntax error, i deleted them all, sorry.

Comment: I only learned python for less than two weeks, so i believe i don't really know what is behind this pattern, how to reach in, how to creat random ships, and place them as a symbol "@" on my board.

Comment: for example, if i chose row 2, column 2 in this pattern. what syntax can place a @ at this coordinate.

Comment: "*for what i tried i got syntax error*", still, it's preferable to include that in your question as is shows what you're trying to do and wher you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates (and prints) a nested list of O's:

```py
board = []
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
for row in board:
    print(" ".join(row))
```

```
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
```

To better understand the `board` structure, let's show it as is, without formatting it:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

You can see that it is a list (recognized by the `[ ]` brackets) with 5 other lists in it, which each contain 5 times the character 'O'.

If you want to change the element on the 2nd row from the top, and in the 2nd column from the left you need to access that element first.

Note that Python lists are 0-based, so you access the first element by the index 0.

To access the 2nd row from the top, you need to access the nested list at position 1:

```py
board[1]
```

Inside that row, you want to index the 2nd column from the left, which is the value at position 1. As you have now indexed the correct position, you can set it to another value:

```py
board[1][1] = '@'
```

If you show the `board` variable again you'll see:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', '@', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed explanation. now i understand the struction and syntax.